# Cannot add foreign key when importing from php my admin

Tags: mysql, foreign-keys

I have the following sql script:

```
use restaurant;
set foreign_key_checks=0;
create table rtable_schedule(
    id int(11) not null,
    rdate date not null,
    start_hour tinyint,
    start_min tinyint,
    end_hour tinyint,
    end_min tinyint,
    foreign key (id,rdate) references rtable(id,reservation_date),
    primary key (id,rdate)
);
```

However when I import it via phpmyadmin I get the following error:

`#1215 - Cannot add foreign key constraint`
Any ideas how can that be solved?Notice that rtable already exists

Comment: Does `rtable` have both `id` and `reservation_date` as conbined primary key?

Comment: no it has id as primary key

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Here's](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/create-table-foreign-keys.html) the MySQL documentation for Foriegn Keys, this is what it says:

> InnoDB permits a foreign key to reference any column or group of
>   columns. However, in the referenced table, there must be an index
>   where the referenced columns are listed as the first columns in the
>   same order.
>
> NDB requires an explicit unique key (or primary key) on any column
>   referenced as a foreign key.

As `reservation_date` column is not a part of a primary key, it's likely that it won't have an index in `rtable`. I would recommend creating an index on `reservation_date` column before creating a table with `Foreign Key`.

Comment: sorry but I am new to sql.What do you mean by creating an index?